# Why won't JavaScript let me scrape webpages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping

In trying to advance my skills in Javascript, I am attempting to make a little webpage that will scrape static articles from Wikipedia. I have the page all set up, and everything works in creating links and an iframe. But when I try to access the contents of the iframe:

```
function getIframeContent(frameId) {
    var frameObj = 
        document.getElementById(frameId);

    var frameContent = frameObj.
        contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    
    alert("frame content : " + frameContent);
}
```

It throws this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://nottimtam.github.io" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at getIframeContent (https://nottimtam.github.io/wikipedia-scraper/main.js:44:23)
at trigger_download (https://nottimtam.github.io/wikipedia-scraper/main.js:50:25)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (https://nottimtam.github.io/wikipedia-scraper/:22:54)
```

So I researched the cross-origin error and I understand why it exists. What I don't understand is why I cannot download the static text and images on this page? I can do something very similar, without issue, with BeautifulSoup in Python...

I am VERY new to Javascript so it is likely that I am just overlooking something.

Here's my code: https://github.com/NotTimTam/wikipedia-scraper/tree/gh-pages

The scraper is running from here: https://nottimtam.github.io/wikipedia-scraper/

Comment: Your browser is not going to let you access a cross site domain in an iframe.  This is a security mechanism that most (if not all) browsers implement.

Comment: search for CORS, and you will see that in a browser, if you are on a domain, you can't get informations from other domains that does not explicitly allows CORS (in poor words)

Comment: Is there an alternative I can use to download static webpages?

Comment: Server proxies that perform the requests to the secondary server, thus bypassing browser cross site constraints.

Comment: Why do you want it in JS? As you said, it's no problem with Python, and won't be a problem with any server side language.

Comment: Just start Chrome with the flag (--disable-web-security) that disable the security.

Comment: I am doing it in JS because I want it to be a website and because I am trying to learn JS.

Comment: With NodeJS in this case perhaps? Still written in JS, but serverside

Comment: Even if you could access it you wouldn't be able to save anything. You want node for this.